# ActiveRecord Associations vs PostgreSQL Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, activerecord

I've been using PostgreSQL arrays to store group members and administrators in a Rails Project.

So my table looked like this:

   `Column    |            Type
-------------+-----------------------------
 id          | bigint
 name        | character varying
 members     | character varying[]
 admins      | character varying[]
 description | text
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone`

But recently I switched to ActiveRecord many-to-many associations, because it made the code easier to read and because everyone else does it.

But which solution is better in terms of performance? Are the PostgreSQL Arrays be faster because they don't need another table or am I missing something?

Comment: you forget data integrity, foreign keys etc exist to ensure the whole is solid

Comment: I would say it depends. In certain cases data normalization is more performant than having tables join each other. What's your use case for members and admins? if those are frequently updated it might be best to separate the data into distinct tables. If you're just reading from them, then I would say that having them saved as a collection is more performant